# How to run a command before the machine automatically shuts down?

Tags: shutdown

How can I run a command before the machine automatically shuts down?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatic shutdown"? Should it be run before the machine is shut down by a cron or before every shutdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about to put a script in the correct runlevel?
I think runlevel 6 is shutdown, and then the directory to play in is

```
/etc/rc6.d/
```

Comment: This is more or less equivalent to what @geekosaur suggested.

Comment: Note that this gets really complicated, as you have to make the script /etc/rc6.d/K##something to order it properly. An upstart job would be simpler

Comment: Runlevel 6 is reboot, not shutdown.  Runlevel 0 is system halt (aka shutdown), but at that runlevel, no services (e. g. `cron`) will be running.

Answer (score 6):

`cron` isn't the tool for this.  You need to set up an `upstart` job which executes during shutdown, preferably declaring a dependency so that it runs before any services it requires shut down.  `man 5 init` for the details on how to properly define a startup or shutdown task; I can't help beyond that without more information, as it depends on what you're trying to do and what other `upstart` jobs it depends on.

Comment: My question is : How to run a command automatically before the machine shutdown?

Comment: I mount firefox *.profile directory with tmpfs in ram at startup .
When I shutdown machine , I want to tar that profile directory to a file automatically to keep the content.

Comment: So, as `man 5 init` tells you, there are several ways to define an `upstart` job for this: it could be a `script` triggered `start on shutdown`, or more accurately `start on stopping mountall`. Or you could `start on started mountall` and `stop on stopping mountall`, and use `pre-start` to create, `mount`, and populate the ramdisk and `post-stop` to save and `umount` it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, replacing `$HOME` and `$PROFILE` with vapid values and save it to `~/.init` with permission `644`.

Before you do anything, make sure there is a line like

```
firefox /home/your_name/.mozilla/firefox/your_profile.default tmpfs size=128M,noauto,user,exec,uid=1000,gid=100 0 0
```

in `/etc/fstab`, where the mount option `noauto` prevents tmpfs from being auto-mounted, which could be changed to `auto` to your preference. I leave it there to keep the whole upstart job in integrity.

```
description     "automatic firefox profile ram caching"

start on started mountall
stop on stopping mountall
env HOME="/home/your_name"
env PROFILE="your_profile.default"

script
if test -z "$(mount | grep -F "${HOME}/.mozilla/firefox/${PROFILE}" )"
then
mount "${HOME}/.mozilla/firefox/${PROFILE}"
fi
end script


post-start script
cd "${HOME}/.mozilla/firefox"
if test -f packed.tar
then
    tar xpf packed.tar
    echo "$(date): firefox profile unpacked to ram" >> unpack.log
else
    tar xpf packed.tar.old
    echo "$(date): backup profile unpacked to ram" >> unpack.log
fi
touch "${PROFILE}/.unpacked"
end script 


pre-stop script
cd "${HOME}/.mozilla/firefox"
if test -f "${PROFILE}/.unpacked"
then
    tar --exclude '.unpacked' -cpf packed.tmp.tar "$PROFILE"
    mv packed.tar packed.tar.old
    mv packed.tmp.tar packed.tar
    rm "$PFORILE/.unpacked"
    echo "$(date) firefox profile packed from ram" >> pack.log
else
    echo ".unpacked is missing. pack current session data to newfile"
    tar -cpf packed-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M).tar "$PROFILE"
fi
end script
```

Answer (score 1):

As a simplified version of funicorn's answer.. an upstart job, either in /etc/init/foo.conf or as ~/.init/foo.conf :

```
start on starting rc RUNLEVEL=6
task
exec myscript
```

This will run, and block the entire shutdown until "myscript" exits.

That is all you need. Note that the user jobs (~/.init/foo.conf) are a very new feature and on my 12.04 system with ecryptfs /home do not work, so you may just have to put the job in /etc/init.