# Extremely slow ACPI Event Propagation

Tags: 13.04, server, 14.04, acpi, events

A follow up to my previous question here: [Run a Script when Power Button is Pushed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473693/run-a-script-when-power-button-is-pushed)

So I am able to detect ACPI events and I intercept the power button press appropriately, however there is an indeterminate amount of time between the power button being pressed and the script actually running. In some cases, there is a minute-long delay between when I physically push the button and when the script gets run. In others, the script runs almost immediately after I press the button.

What could cause such a delay in the event propagation?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem under Debian with a `3.2.0-4-amd64` Kernel. When this happens I see in `/var/log/syslog` the following error messages: `acpid: netlink read error: No buffer space available (105)`, `acpid: too many errors reading via netlink - aborting`. Do you see the same? Did you solve the problem eventually?

Comment: Could you fix it after all?

Answer (score 0):

Running `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd` fixed it for me.

I had been getting this on Ubuntu 20.04.

The cause was the notification daemon not running. Something tries to connect to it, and takes some time to time out.